# Removing a node from a doubly linked list using classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to detach a node from a doubly linked list using a class but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. I have gotten my function to remove the front but once try again to remove the front I get a segmentation fault or when I try to remove anything else than the front the node, the node is still displayed in my list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    void seperate(Node *p){
       if (p->getPrev() == nullptr){  //element being deleted is the front
             front = p->getNext(); //change front to next element
       }
       else{
           ((p->getPrev())->getNext())->setNext(p->getNext());
            }
       if(p->getNext() == nullptr){ //Element being delete is the back
           back = p->getPrev(); //change back pointer to the prev element
       }
       else{
          ((p->getNext())->getPrev())->setNext(p->getPrev());
       }
       p->setNext(nullptr);
       p->setPrev(nullptr);
       size--;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't provide a [mcve] The first mistake was not checking for null input.

Comment: I forgot this part, but I only use this function with a precondition that the node is in the list. otherwise I don't use the function :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line isn't quite right:

```
((p->getPrev())->getNext())->setNext(p->getNext());
```

In particular, `((p->getPrev())->getNext())` is always going to evaluate out to `p`, which isn't what you intended -- I believe you are trying to modify the next-pointer of the node before `p`, not the next-pointer of `p` itself.

So I think you want something more like this:

```
p->getPrev()->setNext(p->getNext());
```

... and you'll need to make a similar change to your `((p->getNext())->getPrev())->setNext(p->getPrev());` line as well.

Comment: yes that fixed it! Thank you so much! I swear I had tried that because I tried drawing it out but I guess I didn't do it correctly.